# Why only half the interval of the domain of the solution of a D.E. with no singularities is considered as the solution and why is it usually open?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The solution of the following problem

$y'(x) = 100y(x) -101e^{-x}$

$y(0) = 1 $

is $y(x) = e^{-x}$ for $x \in D$

**I wonder what  the correct set D is**.

In my notes it says $D=(0,+\infty)$, But why? I don't see any singularities in the solution to exclude the rest of the real line. Furthermore if the solution is only considered for $x>0$, $y(0)$ should be undefined then I couldn't say $y(0)=1.$
I usually see that in differential equations only one of the half-intervals determined by "a" in the initial condition $y(a)=y_0$ is taken as the domain of the solution (and it is taken open), like  $(0, +\infty) $in this case. **What is the reason for all this? Would saying the solution is in $D=\mathbb{R}$  or in D=$[0, +\infty)$ make the problem ill-posed?**

Comment: $e^{-x}$ is not a solution for any $D$.

Comment: I fixed a typo sorry, @geetha290krm

Comment: You can take $D=\mathbb R$.